# Null pointer exception on cluster.connect when using Cassandra 2.2.7

Tags: java, ajax, cassandra

I am trying to display all users usernames from a Cassandra database using an AJAX script in the jsp page.This would display a list of the users usernames when a view all button is clicked. However the Server throws a Null pointer exception on Session session = cluster.connect("");

```
java.lang.NullPointerException

    User.searchAll(User.java:87)
    Search.doGet(Search.java:82)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
```

**Model**
public class User {

```
Cluster cluster;

public User() {

}
   public java.util.LinkedList<ProfileBean> searchAll(){

    Session session = cluster.connect("instagrim");
    LinkedList<ProfileBean> profileBeanList = new LinkedList();


    String cqlQuery = "select * from userprofiles";
    PreparedStatement ps = session.prepare(cqlQuery);
    ResultSet rs;
    BoundStatement bs = new BoundStatement(ps);
    rs = session.execute(bs.bind());
    if(rs.isExhausted()){
        System.out.println("Profile not found");
    }
    else
    {
        for (Row row : rs){
        ProfileBean profile = new ProfileBean();
        profile.setLogin(row.getString("login"));
        profileBeanList.add(profile);    
    }

    }
    session.close();
    return profileBeanList;
}
```

**Servlet**

```
public class Search extends HttpServlet {

     Cluster cluster = null;

            public void init(ServletConfig config)
             {
                cluster = CassandraHosts.getCluster();
             }

        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

        User us = new User();
        String output ="";
        LinkedList<ProfileBean> profileBeanList = new LinkedList();
        profileBeanList = us.searchAll();
        for (int i=0;i<profileBeanList.size();i++)
        {
                output="<p>"+profileBeanList.get(i).getLogin() +"</p>";
        }
        response.getWriter().write(output);
        RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("search.jsp");
        rd.forward(request,response);


}
```

Comment: It looks, the connection is failed. check your key space name 'instagrim' is correct. if correct, make sure your cluster is initialised within your application and reachable.

Answer (score 0):

cluster is null, therefore it does not have a connect method. The system lets you know about the situation with the error message.

The solution is to make sure that cluster is properly initialized before you try to connect.

Comment: public class Search extends HttpServlet {
    
    Cluster cluster = null;

    public void init(ServletConfig config){
        cluster = CassandraHosts.getCluster();
    }

Comment: I have this, at the top of the Search servlet, still getting the same error.

Comment: @RhysHovell, I do not see it

Comment: Every other method in the class has the same line of code, all work except this one.

Comment: @RhysHovell it might be called before it is initialized. The situation is not changed. Initialize cluster before you use it. public Cluster getCluster() {if (cluster == null) {cluster = CassandraHosts.getCluster();} return cluster} and call getCluster which initializes cluster if it has not been initialized.